# Express test using JEST and ESM give me error "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sum' of object '[object Module]'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, es6-modules

i tried to using jest for mocking imported function but i got this error `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` or `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sum' of object '[object Module]'`, i expect that i got return value that i mocked in this test

Attempt 1

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import * as util from "./util.js"

it("TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sum' of object '[object Module]'", () => {
  jest.spyOn(util, "sum").mockImplementation(() => { return 2 })
  
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(2);
})
```

Attempt 2

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import { sum } from './util.js'

it("TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sum' of object '[object Module]'", () => {
  jest.mock("./util.js", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    sum: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(2),
  }));
  
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(2);
})
```

Attempt 3

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import { sum } from "./util.js"

it("TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.", () => {
  sum = jest.fn(() => { return 2 })
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(2);
})
```

i'm following jest documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules to setup my config

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  },
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = async () => {
  return {
    verbose: true,
    transform: {}
  };
};
```

i created this repo for reproduction https://github.com/fei1990a/jest-esm/tree/main

Thankyou for any help

Answer (score 4):

Here is the workaround I came up with.

```
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

beforeAll(() => {
  jest.unstable_mockModule("./util.js", () => ({
    sum: jest.fn(() => { return 2 }),
  }));
});

afterAll(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

test("should sum value be 2", async () => {
  const { sum } = await import("./util.js");
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(2);
});
```

Reference : https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10025

Comment: The current problem with Jest and `unstable_mockModule` is that you can't do a partial mock of a module which makes testing inner functions etc impossible atm - only simple cases as above which don't actually do anything - you're testing a mock and not actually testing `sum`.